# !important flag in variables and operations in SCSS

Tags: css, angular, sass, material-design, angular-material

I am importing a modified version of [this Material SCSS](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/checkbox/checkbox.scss%5D) because I need to be able to override the sizes of the checkbox. I have successfully done something similar with radio buttons, so I know I'm on the right track.

The problem is, when I defined the variables at the top of the file, like this:

```
$mat-checkbox-size: 12vw !default;
$mat-checkbox-border-width: 0.5vw;
$mat-checkbox-transition-duration: 90ms;
$_mat-checkbox-ripple-radius: 2vw;
```

...the code has no effect. However, I know from my experience with the radio buttons that I must add an `!important` flag to the `$mat-checkbox-size`:

```
$mat-checkbox-size: 12vw !important;
```

However, this causes the SCSS compilation to fail. The line causing the failure is this:

```
$_mat-checkbox-mark-stroke-size: 2 / 15 * $mat-checkbox-size !default;
```

I receive the following error:

> Error:
>
> $_mat-checkbox-mark-stroke-size: 2 / 15 * $mat-checkbox-size !default;
>
> Undefined operation: "0.13333 times 12vw !important".

How can I perform operations in SCSS using variables that include this `!important` flag?

Comment: what's the expected result of multiplying `!important` and some number? In what world will it make sense?

Comment: Can you give !important at the place where you are using these variables? Just give it a try.

Comment: @smnbbrv I'm not trying to multiply `!important`, I'm trying to indicate that the variable should override the previously defined variable in the Material SCSS

Comment: @rach8garg What do you mean? If I don't specify `!important` at the time of variable declaration, it has it's previous value for some reason

Comment: Found a solution ? Not sure if variables can be overridden.